# Drag floating images in a View

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I have a activity with a map and a custom view over it:

I want to drag a image mark freely over this view, so I can trace a line between 4 of this markers.

Somehow similar to Overlay Marker of Google Map. But the Marker of Map is not so good, because I have to press and hold, to enable drag. I like a more freely behaviour.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".MapFragment">


    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    <br.com.alexpfx.tracker.soccer.view.FieldFrame
        android:id="@+id/fieldFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may choose from the available touch gestures given in [Dragging and Scaling](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html) which were implemented using `onTouchEvent()` to intercept touch events.

As mentioned, the touch gestures that you can use are the following:

- Drag an object
- Drag to Pan
- Use Touch to Perform Scaling

More information and sample snippets can be found in the given documentation.

Comment: the point is not about drag, but to free drag a view inside another view.